# Using z3c.jbot to override Plone document_view

Tags: overriding, plone

I'm working with Plone 4.0.7 & Python 2.6.7 on Mac OSX 10.7:

I need to tweak the document_view just slightly when in a specific segment of my site so I want to add a conditional to the document.pt. I'm trying to use z3c.jbot to do this but for some reason my changes aren't showing. I'm using the file name **Products.CMFDefault.browser.templates.document.pt** in order to override the file. I use z3c.jbot all the time and I'm really not sure why this isn't working so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably want to override (in a skin layer) one of these files instead:

- main_template.pt
  ([plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_templates/main_template.pt](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.sunburst/blob/master/plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_templates/main_template.pt) or
  [Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/main_template.pt](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/main_template.pt))
- document_view.pt ([Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/document_view.pt](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/document_view.pt))